# How to write a LINQ Query to keep the most recent 10 entries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table that I wish to only keep the most recent 10 records.  If I were to write the query targeting MySQL, it would look something like the following:

```
DELETE FROM tblQuickLink 
WHERE ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT ID from tblQuickLink 
      ORDER BY EntryDate DESC 
      Limit 10)
```

I would like to construct a Linq query that would give me a collection of records which I would then use to remove from the target table by iterating thru the list and issuing a `dbContext.Delete`.  I'm new to Linq and Entity Framework so if there's an easier way to achieve this then I'm all ears.

Thanks a bunch.

-- Val

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.  I'm actually converting from a MySQL database to a SQL Server DB.  Are you suggesting that I can actually issue the above query directly to the Context?

Comment: @Silvermind Would SQL actually lock the table during the query? Even if so, once the query executes, new records could be immediately added. I'm not sure the difference is enough to matter unless the removal is part of an after insert trigger.

Comment: @Silvermind Perhaps asking how many records are likely to be deleted would be worthwhile then, before assuming it will be a problem. But LINQ certainly isn't good for everything, and EF even less sometimes.

Comment: @Silvermind For all the benefits LINQ brings normally - e.g. type safety and standard language usage.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the input. I'm learning a lot and I truly appreciate all of the feedback.  I ended up getting my data using a FromSqlRaw command and then issuing a RemoveRange command.  The table is relatively small, it holds the last 10 contact records a user accessed.  I've only got 8 users so the table will never grow to more than 80 records. I'll re-evaluate at a later time if that number starts to grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LINQ never changes the original input sequence!**

You can only extract data from your input sequence. You can materialize this data and kindly ask the DbSet of your DbContext to delete these elements.

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    // get all but the 10 newest records
    var rowsToDelete = dbContext.QuickLinks
        .OrderByDescending(quickLink => quickLink.EntryDate)
        .Skip(10)
        .ToList();

    dbContext.QuickLinks.RemoveRange(rowsToDelete);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

In words: MyDbContext contains a table of QuickLinks. Every Row in this table has a property EntryDate. Order the rows in the table of QuickLinks by descending value of EntryDate. The result is a sequence of rows with the newest EntryDate first. Skip the first 10 elements of this sequence, and put the rest in a list.

Ask the QuickLinks to remove all elements that are in the resulting list, and save the changes.

Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: Don't call ToList(); on the rowsToDelete query, it is will return all records from DB first before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not EF expert, not even beginner, but maybe this will work:

```
context.RemoveRange(context.tblQuickLink.OrderByDescending(x => x.EntryDate).Skip(10));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Query just retrieves data, so it cannot delete anything. You need to use RemoveRange method.